# UITableView - Prevent overscroll without disabling bounce

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there anyway to prevent a tableview from being dragged down past the top while still allowing it to bounce?

I have a tableview that I can drag up to cover full-screen. When dragging it back down, it will sometimes still be in scrolling mode so instead of dragging the entire container view down, it will allow the tableview to scroll beyond the top.

If I disable bounce, this fixes it but I'd like to somehow keep the bounce but disable the ability to catch it in that state and continue dragging.

Something like:

```
if (isBouncing){
    _tableview.enabled = NO;
}else{
    _tableview.enabled = YES;
}
```

I also tried the below code but it basically does the same thing as [_tableView setBounces:NO]

```
if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0) {
    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
}
```

Comment: This question needs some clarification. It's impossible to have a bounce effect without over scrolling. Are you talking about bounce effects in nested views?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think this answer should help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/28570023/4755417

```swift
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView!, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafePointer<CGPoint>) {

     var pageWidth = Float(200 + 30)
     var currentOffset = Float(scrollView.contentOffset.x)
     var targetOffset = Float(targetContentOffset.memory.x)
     var newTargetOffset = Float(0)
     var scrollViewWidth = Float(scrollView.contentSize.width)

     if targetOffset > currentOffset {
         newTargetOffset = ceilf(currentOffset / pageWidth) * pageWidth
     } else {
         newTargetOffset = floorf(currentOffset / pageWidth) * pageWidth
     }

     if newTargetOffset < 0 {
         newTargetOffset = 0
     } else if newTargetOffset > currentOffset {
         newTargetOffset = currentOffset
     }

     Float(targetContentOffset.memory.x) == currentOffset

     scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(CGFloat(newTargetOffset), 0), animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGPoint p = scrollView.contentOffset;
    if(scrollView.contentOffset.y<0)
    {   p.y=0;
        scrollView.contentOffset = p;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding this to `scrollViewDidScroll` and it prevented from over scrolling when dragging but allowed over scrolling by deceleration (bounce):

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y <= 0.0) {
        scrollView.scrollEnabled = false
        scrollView.scrollEnabled = true
    }
}
```